# Liferay Site URL Mapping with Virtual Host

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, virtualhost

I have developed a site in `liferay 6.2 ce ga1` and assigned Virtual Host to portal in `portal-ext.properties web.server.host=domain web.server.http.port=80`. When i assign friendly url to sites developed in site administration unable to add Virtual Host Name. 
How to map http://domain/web/siteone to http://newdomain.com

Answer (score 0):

Access Site Settings by navigating to Site Administration and clicking Site Settings from the Configuration section on the left panel. There you should be able to configure Virtual Hosts. The tab allows you to define a domain name (i.e., www.mycompany.com) for your site. This can be a full domain or a subdomain.